# When allowCredentials is true, allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value "*"

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I upgrade to Spring Boot 2.4.9, the app shows error like this:

```
[10:07:07:487] [ERROR] - org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:175) - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When allowCredentials is true, allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value "*" since that cannot be set on the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header. To allow credentials to a set of origins, list them explicitly or consider using "allowedOriginPatterns" instead.
    at org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration.validateAllowCredentials(CorsConfiguration.java:473) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration.checkOrigin(CorsConfiguration.java:577) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor.checkOrigin(DefaultCorsProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor.handleInternal(DefaultCorsProcessor.java:116) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor.processRequest(DefaultCorsProcessor.java:95) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:141) ~[spring-session-core-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82) ~[spring-session-core-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:97) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.4.9.jar!/:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar!/:?]
```

why would this happen? what should I do to fix this problem? I read the Spring Boot issue, but I still not figure out what the advantage and disadvantage about allowedOrigins contains special char "*"? why should I specify `allowedOriginPatterns` ?

Comment: Show your source code.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually，the solution has been given on the terminal .Both following two methods can solve the problem.

1. Just change **config.addAllowedOrigin("*");** in your programs into **config.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");**
2. Alternatively，set "config.setAllowCredentials(false);"

Answer (score 3):

It is CORS SPEC, you can use `setAllowCredentials(true)` together with `setAllowedOrigins(*)`

Below is from Spring Document for method `setAllowedOrigins()`:

```
/**
     * Keep in mind however that the
     * CORS spec does not allow {@code "*"} when {@link #setAllowCredentials
     * allowCredentials} is set to {@code true} and as of 5.3 that combination
     * is rejected in favor of using {@link #setAllowedOriginPatterns
     * allowedOriginPatterns} instead.
     */
```